# Vertically centering text in square (flex) divs

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm building a game with a grid of cells with some specific constraints but I can't get the CSS right to do all that:

- There should be 9 cells in each row (so `width: 11.11%`).
- Each cell should have square size (managed with `div:before { content: ''; float: left; padding-top: 100%; }`).
- Each cell contains one digit horizontally and vertically centered within the cell.
- The game should be responsive, so cell's can shrink together with the text on mobile (I'm currently playing with `font-size` and media queries).

I got up to the point where all of these are ok, except the vertically centering of the text within a cell. Anyone knows what the trick is or if that just isn't possible and I should create images for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in flex container use:

```
justify-content:center
align-items: center
```

look also on [this guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)